# In Minecraft Comes Alive, how can I make a baby after losing one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-comes-alive

On Minecraft Comes Alive (Mod; Candy Floss World 1.7.10), how do I make a baby if my baby is lost? I accidentally cleared my inventory and my baby disappeared, but it still says:

> You Already Have A Baby

Comment: /give @p baby  :3

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket in that situation I thought it lost its relevant NBT data, and would refuse to be placed.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that is impossible. Try getting another wife, and see if that works

Answer (score -1):

You have to find a priest.Search the internet for what does a priest look like.*You'll find one in a village*

Comment: Why not include an image of a priest or at least a link?